# For a dropdown how to add the class for the single option

Tags: php, css, yii

In the yii how can i had the class for the each option in the dropdownList.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:-
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'img_category_id', CHtml::listdata(CategoryMaster::model()->findAll(array("order" => 'LOWER(category_name) ASC')), 'category_id', 'category_name'),array('class'=>'your class'); ?>
```

Comment: for every option i need to add the class not for all